# Setting User Permission to hide products of other user

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, dashboard

I have a model where there will be many users. Each user has dashboard access and can add there products.. this all is done, but what I want is one user doesn't see other user products. Right now a user can see all products uploaded by all users. Currently Craft CMS doesn't have permission settings to hide entries of other user as they have for channel entries.. but I need that. Can anyone help me how can I achieve that. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has been rolled back to its original form. Please don't edit a question so dramatically after an answer has already been submitted.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a feature request really.  And/or possible a use case for Craft 3s forthcoming multi-site features.  Although C3 + Commerce for it is a ways off yet (6 to 9 months apparently)

You could perhaps use something like a custom field for the 'owner' of each product, and Zenbu to set up filtered views for each of the editors (just guessing, I've not used Zenbu personally)

https://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu-craftcms